# Fullscreen mode still not taking effect with Firefox 57

Tags: javascript, firefox, web-applications, fullscreen, manifest.json

Just installed the long awaited Firefox 57 on my Android and am disappointed to see that Fullscreen still does not work :-( even though it was heralded [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Releases/57)

"The fullscreen value of the Web App Manifest display field is now supported in Firefox for Android 57 (bug 1126479)."

Has anyone got this working?

Try my [Brotkrumen](https://hypocampus.applications.uwa.edu.au/travelmanager.html) Web App for an example.

Here is my manifest: -

```
{
  "short_name": "Brotkrumen",
  "name": "Brotkrumen Web App",
  "description": "Native Background Geolocation POC",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "gingerbreadhouse.png",
      "sizes": "48x48 128x128 144x144",
      "type": "image/png"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": "TravelManager.html",
  "background_color": "#00ccdd",
  "theme_color": "#00ccdd",
  "display": "fullscreen"
}
```

Comment: only thing I can think of is `TravelManager.html`  vs `travelmanager.html`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1418701) it will ship in 58. Don't know why it was delayed.

Quote: -

"Oh I see the problem -- that particular bug landed in 57, but PWA are not
enabled at all until 58. Hope this clears things up."